# Кнопки на чистом css

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка

Пытаюсь сделать кнопку входа на сайт, при наведении курсора из-за края кнопки к центру медленно выезжает стрелка.
Стрелка появляется, но без замедления сразу возникает на нужном месте. Помогите найти багу, уже всю голову сломал

```
#btn {
  position: relative; 
  border: 3px solid #f9ea70;
}
#btn:after{
  content: "\f178";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  position: absolute;   
  display: none;
  right: -20px;
  transition: right 0.9s ease-in-out;    
}
#btn:hover:after {
  display: inline-block;
  right: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Свойство `display` - не анимируемое, отсюда и отсутствие анимации.

Вместо этого скрывайте вашу иконку с помощью `opacity` и `visibility` (при необходимости):

```css
#btn {
  position: relative;
  border: 3px solid #f9ea70;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#btn:after {
  content: "\f178";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  right: -20px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.9s ease-in-out;
}

#btn:hover:after {
  right: 15px;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div id="btn">BTN</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло)